# Registering service with constructor arguments using tsyringe

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, stenciljs, tsyringe

I have a service to handle some data-fetching and I am trying to use tsyringe with it, the function to create the service gets called multiple times (i cant really do anything about that), so it is creating many instances of the service. I tried to wrap it in "container.isRegistered" checks, but when I do that it doesn't register the service at all.

What I have so far is:

```
@singleton()
@injectable()
export class Service implements IService {
  constructor(@inject('arg1') arg1: string, @inject('arg2') arg2: string) {
}
```

Then I am registering it here in another file:

```
    if (!container.isRegistered('arg1', true)) {
      container.register('arg1', {useValue: this.arg1});
    }

    if (!container.isRegistered('arg2', true)) {
      container.register('arg2', {useValue: this.arg2});
    }

    if (!container.isRegistered('IService', true)) {
      container.register('IService', {useClass: Service});
    }
```

In another file I resolve it like so:

```
this.service = container.resolve('IService');
```

Trying to check if it is registered stops the Service from being registered at all, but if I don't I have multiple instances running. The service mainly handles data-fetching, it's only supposed to fetch some data once on startup but I am seeing many calls that do so. I put some logs in the service constructor and I can see it being created many times.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating new registry in IoC using method register, in fact you create another link on service that doesn't related to your decorator @singlton inside of class. You need set additional  parameter in the register method. It will describe lifecycle of injectable object. Because be default it doesn't use Singleton. You should do this like that:

```
import { container, autoInjectable, Lifecycle } from 'tsyringe';
...
container.register<UsersService>('IService', {useClass: UsersService},  { lifecycle: Lifecycle.Singleton } );
```

More info [here](https://github.com/microsoft/tsyringe#register) and types [here](https://github-com.translate.goog/microsoft/tsyringe/blob/master/src/types/lifecycle.ts)